# Two 3-way switches wiring to control two lights

Tags: multiway-switch, smart-switch

I did some searches but cannot find the answer(s). I have two 3-way switches that control two lights. I am trying to convert them to smart switches and trying to figure out which kind to get. I opened them up and the pictures below were what I saw and they look different from what I can find in most of the diagrams especially the two black and one white on the left along with black and red wired together.

Will anyone be able to give me some advises of how they were done and how can I convert them to smart switches?

Thank you all very much!

View 1
[image]

View 2
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos looking directly in to the backs of the boxes in question please?

Comment: I added the second view there and hope it helps. I really appreciate it!

Comment: What make and model of smart switch are you planning to use?

Comment: I don't have a preference. Just wanted to make sure I get the right ones and can connect them correctly. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for looking at the wiring *before* buying the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching and testing, I think I have found the answer of my own question. First, the YouTube video: https://youtu.be/kwydife035I was very helpful for me to get an idea of where to start.

I tested both outlets and apparently the previous person who wired the cable did not follow the conventional colors but here are what I found out:

[image]

So I purchased the TP-Link Kasa 3-way switch and connected the neutral wire together and connected the line and travelers together only on the main switch (the left picture) and I kept the secondary switch as is and I was able to successfully converted it to a smart switch.

Hope it's helpful for anyone who needs it.

Cheers!

Comment: Using the white as a traveler has got to be against code, even if it works. I'm sure one of the electricians will comment...